# I run the python open alrp project but I am getting a file not found error

Tags: python, openalpr

I'm trying to use the python openalrp plate reading project, but I get an error. can you please help?

```
parser.add_argument("--config", dest="config", action="store", 
default="ALRP/openalpr.conf",
              help="Path to openalpr.conf config file" )
parser.add_argument("--runtime_data", dest="runtime_data", action="store", 
   default="ALRP/runtime_data",
              help="Path to OpenALPR runtime_data directory" )
parser.add_argument('plate_image', help='License plate image file')
options = parser.parse_args()
```

The error definition is as follows:

usage: test.py

```
           [-h] [-c COUNTRY] [--config CONFIG]
           [--runtime_data RUNTIME_DATA]
           plate_image
           test.py: error: the following arguments are required: plate_image
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be an airp problem.

If you looked at the *stacktrace* of the error (by not catching it) you would see that it comes from `argparse`.

Because of the line:

```
parser.add_argument('plate_image', help='License plate image file')
```

You need to pass the argument `plate_image` to the program.